# Definir cores padrões no materialize

Tags: materialize

Gostaria de saber se tem como definir um padrão cores no framework materialize, como por [exemplo é feito no Material Design](https://getmdl.io/customize/index.html). Isso evitaria inserir a cor de um elemento em cada um

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer isso é melhor você usar um pré-processador de css tipo [Sass](http://sass-lang.com), que o materialize da suporte.

Ai é só baixar o [source em sass do Materialize](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html), la dentro você vai ter 
as pastas `fonts`, `js` e `sass`, que é a pasta que importa.

Dentro da pasta sass você terá a pasta `components` e dentro dela terá a `_color.scss`, dentro dela terão todas as cores do framework, ai é só alterar e compilar o materialize e você terá sua versão de materialize customizado.

Caso você não conheça essa técnologia, ela é fácil de se aprender, comecei a apenas 1 mês e ja estou conseguindo me virar bem.

O Sass foi feito com base no [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/), então pra compilar ele você vai precisar do ruby na sua máquina ou você pode usar a versão [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) também. Eu sugiro você usar a versão node ai você pode gerenciar esse as tarefas de compilar os `.scss`. Com node eu acho melhor usar o [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com), caso você ja conheça e prefira também da pra usar [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com).

Vou deixar um exemplo com `Gulp`:

Caso não conheça, estude um pouco o básico do gulp, mas adiantando

- Baixe node
- Depois baixe o `gulp-cli`: `npm install gulp-cli -g`
- Se seu projeto não for um projeto gerenciado pelo `npm`, de um `npm init` e siga as instruções para criar o `package.json`
- Baixe o `gulp`, `gulp-sass` e `gulp-watch`

  - `npm install gulp --save-dev`
  - `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`
  - `npm install gulp-watch --save-dev`
- Dentro do seu projeto crie um arquivo com o nome de `gulpfile.js`
- Cole esse bloco de código dentro do seu `gulpfile.js`

---

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
  gulp.src('materialize/sass/materialize') // aqui estou dizendo qual o arquivo principal de sass a compilar
    .pipe(
    sass({
      includePaths: ['materialize/sass'] // aqui estou mostrando quais pastas possuem os imports que meu arquivo principal usa
    })
      .on("error", sass.logError) // caso haja algum erro ele loga no console que você executar a task gulp
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css')); // ele vai jogar o materialize compilado na pasta css
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('materialize/sass/**/*.scss', ['compileSass']); 
  // aqui eu estou falando que o gulp vai "assistir" qualquer alteração em qualquer arquivo .scss 
     do meu projeto e a cada alteração ele vai compilar pra mim, é bom para desenvolver
});
```